# How can you get your historic location data from new iPhones with iOS 5 (for personal use)?

Tags: iphone, ios, location

It used to be easy to get your historic location data from a file called consolidated.db on an iPhone (see, for example, http://petewarden.github.com/iPhoneTracker/). However, this is more difficult on new iOS systems. Is your data still somewhere on your phone, though, and is it possible to access it?

To be clear, I'm not looking to use the location API; rather, I'd like my historic location data as an end-user of my device. Are there any scripts/apps available that can do this for me?

Comment: FWIW I don't think iOS devices cache this data nearly as long as they did back when it was discovered that iOS devices did hold onto this data.

Comment: And now you have to write a daemon yourself that runs in the background and spies on the user (**NO!**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really answer my own question (I'm still interested in iPhone historical location data, so please answer if you have any ideas!), but there are apps that will allow you to store your location data:

- OpenPaths, http://openpaths.cc/, which seems to provide the most control and a good policy about how they handle your data (I've not used it before, but if anyone has any insights, they're certainly welcome.
- Google Latitude, http://www.google.com/latitude, which allows you to export 30 days of location data in KML format.

Both of these exist for both iOS and Android.