# Accessing Location data stored in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, geolocation

Is it possible to access the location/file which stores the "Location data" being captured by the Location service, when we switch "Location Service On" in iOS Device. ?

I want to access the file & its content from my app ?
I have tried looking for it, but results points to the usage of "Core-Location Framework".

If anybody has some idea, please share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location data stored inside “consolidated.db” cannot be accessed by Safari or any apps. But yeah there is a security risk if someone steal your phone, could look at the file and see where you have been.

Comment: So the file "consolidated.db" is not accessible from within the app & hence there is no means by which I can encrypt the file, in case the phone is lost..? At least path information of the file on the device ..?

Comment: No it is not possible. Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514548/how-can-you-get-your-historic-location-data-from-new-iphones-with-ios-5-for-per